# Redirecting search keyword from one webpage search box to another web page search box

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, search

I am trying to search for a keyword from the search box of webpage X and redirect it as an input keyword to the search box of webpage Y. I am able to redirect it to the page 'Y' from 'X' but the search keyword is vanishing once it's redirected to page 'Y'. Can somebody share your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: Such a post by a 5k+ member, honestly.

Comment: I am new to php, javascripting. Sorry if the post is vague.

Comment: The question is both unclear and too broad. Have you any code that you tried? We'd be glad to look at it ;-)

Comment: pass it as query parameters, store in local storage ( if under same domain) or do sth of the 1000 other possibilities...

Comment: Well, given the question, it does seem like you do have code. Up until that we know which animal(s) we're dealing with here, the question remains unclear and too broad. There isn't much that I can do here. Wait for others to offer suggestions, that stand to help and also "not" help.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving the keyword to `$_POST` echoing it to the next page. Here is an untested, ballpark example:

```
<input type="search" id="search" />
<input type="hidden" val="" id="save" />

<script>
//uses jquery
$("#search").change(function() {
    keyword = $(this).val();
    $("#save").val(keyword);
}
</script>
```

On the next page,

```
<?php
$keyword = $_POST['save'];
?>

<input type="search" id="next-page-search" <?php echo 'value = ". $keyword ."';?> />
```